# Rational curves vs rational points

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Are rational curves like a higher dimensional generalization of rational points or are they something completely different?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I don't know if this is helping you:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve#Rational_curves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A rational curve is, roughly, a curve which is birational to $\mathbb P^1$ or a tree of copies of $\mathbb P^1$. The precise usage tends to be context-dependent, e.g. depending on whether the geometric or arithmetic genus is the relevant invariant.

If you are interested in a higher dimensional analogue of a rational point, one might consider rational sections of fibrations, which are rational $K$-point with $K$ the function field of the base scheme. Such a gadget roughly gives a flat family of $k$-points ($k$ the ground field) in the fibers, except over some closed subset of the base scheme.